# Setting cell range values based on header and preceding columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a range of cell values equal to their column headings and cell values in column A & B.

Below you will see an image with a green highlighted area, this will be my range I want to populate.

I have shown the `CONCATENATE` in the formula bar, because that is basically what I want to achieve using `VBA`.

[image]

I am well aware that people are going to tell me **where is your code, what have you tried** - and honestly, the code I have is rubbish and doesn't even come close to what I want *(But I have put it below so you can have a laugh and see how lost I am, it does nothing! )*... I honestly don't even know what to search in Google to get myself in the right direction here...

```
Sub Get_Keys()

  '  Dim Report As Excel.Workbook 'The deliverable
  '  Dim ReportSheet As Excel.Worksheet 'Deliverables worksheet
    
   ' Dim Extract As Excel.Workbook 'This workbook
    'Dim ExtractSheet As Excel.Worksheet 'This workbook sheet
    
    'Workbooks.Open "Test_Report.xlsm"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim Report As Workbook
    Dim Current As Workbook
    
    Set Current = ActiveWorkbook
    'Dont update the screen - makes it work faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Headers As Range
    
    Set Headers = Current.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G14:AB15")
    'Grab Some Data and Store it in a "Range" variable
    Set rng = Current.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G19:AB21")
      
     
    
    'Turn on screen updating again - makes Excel usable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
   
End Sub


Public Sub DoAThing()
    Set Current = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Current.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C19:AB21")
    
    With rng.Columns
        .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub DoAnotherThing()
    Set Current = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Current.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G14:AB15")
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    With cel
        Debug.Print .Address & ":" & .Value
    End With
Next cel
    
End Sub
```

Any help would appreciated, even if it is just to articles that I can read which guide me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could do this with a formula directly... it'll be a little more complicated than the CONCATENATE you currently have, but probably easier than VBA, in my opinion. Is VBA a necessity? Btw, thanks for sharing your code... it shows that you have at least attempted something.

Comment: Hey @BigBen I would like to use VBA as there will be more to the macro than setting these values. haha - I actually have a lot more rubbish code, but didn't want to spam the thread.

Comment: You could use VBA to write a formula to the cells in question though (?/)

Comment: Guess I could give that a go - do you have an article I could read to put me in the right direction?

Comment: `ws.Range("C4:F6").Formula = "Yourformula"`.

Comment: Try and not use `ActiveWorkbook` if you can. Instead, qualify your sheet. It avoids unexpected issues

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who commented offering assistance, I think I manged to somewhat figure it out for now. Having a problem with merged cells, but that is tomorrows issue :) Will update again if I figure it out completely.

Below is the code I am using now and it seems to give me what I want.

```
Public Sub DoAThing()
    Set Current = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim mycell As Range
    Set rng = Current.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K19:AB21")
    
    For Each mycell In rng
        mycell.Value = Range("C17").Value & "/" & Cells(mycell.Row, 3).Value & "/" & Cells(mycell.Row, 5).Value & "/" & Cells(14, mycell.Column) & "/" & Cells(15, mycell.Column) 'Range(mycell.Column + "14").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Next mycell
     
     
End Sub
```